# Loosing Access to navigator.gpu in Popup Window

Tags: javascript, webgpu

As part of a small personal project I would like to render a scene using webgpu and display it on a canvas on a popped out window. I have been slowly learning webgpu and have no trouble setting up a basic scene. However, when I move from the original window that loads my HTML file to that one the one that I create as a pop-up, I seem to loose access to the navigator.gpu, and thus am unable to render anything.

Is there any way that I can access navigator.gpu in a popped out window or am a stuck? Reading around I can't find any source that explicitly tells me that I can't have acess in a pop-up. Here is a really basic HTML file illustrating my problem: the first `console.log(navigator.gpu)` occurs in the pop-up window, and the second in the main window.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>
let my_popup_html = 
`
<script>
console.log(navigator.gpu) // undefined
<\/script>  
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
I am a popup window
<body>
</html>
    `
    let my_popup = document.addEventListener(`DOMContentLoaded`,async () => window.open(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([my_popup_html],{ type:"text/html"})),"Test","directories=false","popup=true","status=false","toolbar=false","menubar=false","replace=false"));
    console.log(navigator.gpu) // is defined and I can use to access the webgpu API
</script>
<html>
</html>
```

I am running the latest chromium for context. I suspect there is something going on with security and the fact that my pop-up html is sourced from a blob. However, I am not certain that this is the problem, and am unsure of how to proceed in that case anyhow.
Can anyone offer concrete info on to what the problem is and if it is possible to work around this issue?